# How to do hasMany and belongsToMany at same model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, Employee & FieldReport. I need to create relations based on the following conditions:

> Field report is owned by an employee whose character is absolute
>   (owner's data must be displayed and cannot be edited), where the
>   report field also has a tag to mark who the employees are in that
>   report field.
>
> An employee, himself, has many field reports.

For now, I've made a relationship, something like this:

1. Employee has many Field Reports.
2. Employee belongs to many Field Reports.
3. Field Report belongs to Employee.
4. Field Report belongs to many Employees.

Then I have a problem where PHP doesn't allow the same method name (in the Employee model).
Example:

- Has many has the method name fieldReports ()
- Belongs to many also have the method name fieldReports ()

Whereas if I define the function name custom, I cannot get the value to fill the first pivot column and generate an error like the following:

> SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: field_report_participant.field_report_id (SQL:
>   insert into "field_report_participant" ("id", "participant_id") values
>   ​​(1, 2))

Is there any solution? This is how my scripts looks like:

`Employee.php`

```php
/**
 * Each employee has many fieldReports.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\HasMany
 */
public function fieldReports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FieldReport::class);
}

/**
 * Each employee belongs to many fieldReports.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
 */
public function fieldReports()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(FieldReport::class);
}
```

`FieldReportController.php`

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\RequestFieldReport  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(RequestFieldReport $request)
{
    $fieldReport = $this->data($request, $this->storeImages($request));

    $fieldReport->participants()->sync(
        $request->participants
    );

    return response()->json([
        'created' => true,
        'data' => $fieldReport,
    ], 201);
}
```

`FieldReport.php`

```php
/**
 * Each field report belongs to a company.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
 */
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

/**
 * Each field report belongs to a employee.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsTo
 */
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
}

/**
 * Each field report belongs to many participants.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
 */
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'field_report_participant', 'participant_id', 'id');
}
```

`create_field_reports_table.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFieldReportsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('field_reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('company_id');
            $table->bigInteger('employee_id');
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->text('chronology');
            $table->json('images')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('closed_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('closed_by', 100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('opened_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('opened_by', 100)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('field_reports');
    }
}
```

`field_report_participant_table.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFieldReportParticipantTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('field_report_participant', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('field_report_id');
            $table->bigInteger('participant_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('field_report_participant');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a copy/paste issue, but you can't duplicate the function `public function fieldReports()`; they need to have unique names (PHP should actually throw an error about that, which is why I suspect it's a copy/paste error for this question)

Comment: nope.. I didn't copy paste it.. Just wondering if it works, and it don't.. ahahah

Comment: Haha yeah, function names need to be unique. It's totally valid to define multiple relationships to the same model (although rare for this setup), but at the very least the functions representative of them need to be different. In this case, something like `public function directFieldReport()` and `public function fieldReports()`, modified to use the proper database columns to link them, should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

After an hour pulling off my hair, trying to do a backflip and asked on each different forums, finally I had the answer. Unfortunately, he has no account on this forum and can't give the answer for this question.

The problem is I put a wrong key on the `participants` method which causing the `field_report_id` placed in a wrong place, in this case; `id`. Which is solved by doing this:

```php
/**
 * Each field report belongs to many participants.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
 */
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'field_report_participant', 'field_report_id', 'participant_id');
}
```

And then, on the `Employee` class, I could create exactly different method and link it with the pivot table. Like this:

```php
/**
 * Each employee belongs to many assignedFieldReports.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relationship\BelongsToMany
 */
public function assignedFieldReports()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(FieldReport::class, 'field_report_participant', 'participant_id', 'field_report_id');
}
```

Hopefully, it can help someone facing this exact same issue on the future.